# Spring: Prioritize component if present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have three components with the same superclass, all of them conditional on property. I want to autowire JUST ONE of the components, prioritizing in a specific order. I thought of using `@Order`, but I wonder if it can be used in this scenario or just to order a collection of those components?

**Components**

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("stable.enabled")
public class StableChild extends ParentClass {}
```

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("experimental.enabled")
public class ExperimentalChild extends ParentClass {}
```

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("testing.enabled")
public class TestingChild extends ParentClass {}
```

**How I intend to use**

```
@Component
public class WhateverClass {

  /**
   * I want to autowire TestingChild if it is present, otherwise ExperimentalChild. If it
   * is also not present, then StableChild. If all of them are absent it is okay to throw 
   * the exception because something is wrong with the configurations.
   */
  @Autowired
  private ParentClass component;
}
```

Comment: I would just ensure that only one of those properties is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `@Order` here. All you need to do is to use [Conditional Of Missing bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html)